# Running a function with a sub procedure out of a Personal macro library

Tags: excel, vba

I just switched from Excel 2003 to 2010 and can't get the Sub to recognize the input which is fixed in cell K1.  I like to have this in my Personal book of macros so that it can be executed in any workbook I'm working on.

Thanks.

```
Function Celsius(x As Double) As Double
   Celsius = (x - 32) * (5 / 9)
End Function
```

---

```
Sub conversion()
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "'=PERSONAL.XLS!Celsius(k1)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you running 2003 and 2007 side by side?  If so, see [this kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930480).

Comment: No, I'm not running them side by side.  I probably should restate what I'm after.  Basically I need the code for the sub procedure that calls the function in Excel 2010.  The user defined "Celsius" function works fine in any cell coming up as =Personal.xls!Celsius(D3) [ D3 here is arbitrary etc ].  But when I try to call it with the sub above I get '=PERSONAL.XLS!Celsius(k1).  I have a number in cell k1 to perform the calc on etc, but it loads the user defined function with the leading apostrophe ' which creates a label or text I guess which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The leading apostrophe means the data in the cell is text.  If you get rid of the apostrophe, Excel will evaluate the formula.

```
Sub conversion()
   ActiveCell.Formula = "=PERSONAL.XLS!Celsius(k1)"
End Sub
```

Comment: It's weird but when I do it I get the result

Comment: Sorry too soon, I get the result =PERSONAL.XLS!Celsius('k1') which now puts an apostrophe before and after the k1 which results in an error #Value

Comment: If you want to use the cell name, you have to use ActiveCell.Formula.  Activecell.FormulaR1C1 is a different notation style.

Comment: OK, I see.  That makes all the difference here.  Thanks very much.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as the correct solution.